# Restricting guests from liking a post more than once without logging in (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

I am creating a blog that visitors can "like" each post.  I want to restrict them to only like it one time.  I have researched the different options and I think creating a cookie is the best one for this particular situation.  I'm open to other suggestions though.

Here's the cookie:

> cookies[:liked] = { value: true, expires: 1.year.from_now }

I have placed the cookie in my likes_controller.rb like so:

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @like = Like.new(params[:like])
    if @like.save
      cookies[:liked] = { value: true, expires: 1.year.from_now }
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'Glad you liked the post!'
    else
      redirect_to :back, notice: "Something went wrong liking the post."
    end
  end
end
```

In my _post.html.erb partial where I have my post title, like, and post content here is the "like" portion:

```
<% if cookies[:liked] == true %>
  <div class="pull-right heart liked">♥</div>
<% else %>
  <div class="pull-right heart">
    <%= form_for (Like.new) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, value: post.id %>
      <%= f.submit '♥', class: "hearts" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm not getting any errors but it also doesn't appear to be setting the cookie or doing anything.  Do you have any suggestions or insight?

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is good. You also could use the database session store instead of the cookie based. But this is deprecated in rails 4. You can read more about that in following post: http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/activerecord-sessionstore-gem-extraction-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

So I think your solution is good.

**UPDATE1 :**

I think you overwrite the cookie always if you like a new post. I think you could solve your problem like following:

```
 class LikesController < ApplicationController

   def create
     @like = Like.new(params[:like])
     if @like.save
       cookies["liked_#{params[:like][:post_id]}".to_sym] = { value: true, expires: 1.year.from_now }
       redirect_to :back, notice: 'Glad you liked the post!'
     else
      redirect_to :back, notice: "Something went wrong liking the post."
    end
  end
end
```

And you also have to update your view.

**UPDATE2:**

I tried it on my console with the debugger in one of my projects (I took a model called Job instead of your Post model to simulate the situation):

```
cookies["liked_#{Job.last.id}".to_sym] = { :value => true, :expires => 1.day.from_now }
```

sets the value to true:

```
cookies["liked_#{Job.last.id}".to_sym] => true
```

and in the view:

```
<% if cookies["liked_#{Job.last.id}".to_sym] %>
  <p>cookie set</p>
<% else %>
  <p>cookie not set</p>
<% end %>
```

and this gives me: "cookie set",

**BUT:**

If I reload the page, there is "cookie not set".

If I debug the second time:

```
cookies["liked_#{Job.last.id}".to_sym] => "true"
```

The boolean true is changed to the string "true". I think that is your error.

I would simple change the boolean to a string, while setting the cookie:

```
cookies["liked_#{Job.last.id}".to_sym] = { :value => "true", :expires => 1.day.from_now }
```

In your case:

```
cookies["liked_#{params[:like][:post_id]}".to_sym] = { value: "true", expires: 1.year.from_now }
```

And in the view:

```
<% if cookies["liked_#{Job.last.id}".to_sym] == "true" %>
  <p>cookie set</p>
<% else %>
  <p>cookie not set</p>
<% end %>
```

Btw I would recommend the use of debugger gems if you have such problems in the future :).

Comment: I hadn't thought of the database session option.  Thank you for mentioning!  I'll look into that if I can't get this way to work out.  This is my first time using cookies in rails and I can't get it to work.  I've got something wrong or missing in my code.  Do you see any problems with what I have?

Comment: I think your solution would fix a problem I would have run into once the cookie was set, so thank you!!  It still doesn't look like my cookie is getting set.  Do you know if I need to create a before_filter or initialize it somehow?

Comment: I updated my answer again. I think now your problem is solved. There was a boolean-string problem..